# regular expression to grep the matching string in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I got one list as follows by running the command in subprocess:

```
import os, subprocess
>>> args = "svn ls https://svne1.access.nsn.com/isource/svnroot/scm_fp/trunk"
>>> pi = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
>>> stdout, stderr = pi.communicate()
>>> print stdout
R_FPT_180.15.1.11.1.0/
R_FPT_180.15.1.41/
R_FPT_180.15.1.42/
R_FPT_190.10/
R_FPT_190.11/
R_FPT_190.6.1.0/
R_FPT_2.4.1.22/
R_FPT_3.2.1.70/
```

In the above list I want to grep only "R_FPT_190.10/" and "R_FPT_190.11/" and after grepping these two again which ever is having big number in the last(in the above example 10,11) i need to get the greater one (in the above example i need to get finally "R_FPT_190.11/").
Can anyone help in this ?

Comment: How should the program know which lines to look for? What's special about `R_FPT_190.10`? Is it that there's only one dot? Or is it always those two exact strings you're looking for and they may not both be present?

Comment: Split stdout into lines, then find lines that startswith 'R_FPT_' and then compare the numbers somehow.

Comment: Here "R_FPT_190." will always be constant. the last numbers (here 10,11) after dot will change often. So I have to match "R_FPT_190." commonly after dot i have to match only 2 digits and /(slash) . In this search, I will get two matches in that i need to find which is greater number in the last two digits(in this example 10,11) so finally 11 i need

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

**Ex:**

```
s = """R_FPT_180.15.1.11.1.0/
R_FPT_180.15.1.41/
R_FPT_180.15.1.42/
R_FPT_190.10/
R_FPT_190.11/
R_FPT_190.6.1.0/
R_FPT_2.4.1.22/
R_FPT_3.2.1.70/"""
import re
print(re.findall("R_FPT_\d+\.\d+\/", s))

d = max([int(i.split(".")[-1].rstrip(r"/")) for i in re.findall("R_FPT_\d+\.\d+\/", s)])
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
['R_FPT_190.10/', 'R_FPT_190.11/']
11
```

Comment: This is good ! but, I still I need to compare these two with last digits(here 10,11) and i need greater one (here 11) how can I compare last two digits again

Comment: Updated snippet.

Comment: Thanks a lot rakesh !!! I need whole string not only the last digit. anyhow I will check that i think in your command if i modify i can get the whole thing. Once again Thanks alot

Comment: Please accept and up vote ans if it solved your problem. Thanks